# php, mysql dynamicaly dropdown using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

i am trying to create a dynamic dropdown menu for my website to add address like state, city, area and postcode. i am using code is working when i try one by one preview in live browser but it does not work when i try to use java-script its not show the data in dropdown menucan you plese tell me where i am making mistake

it is index.php

```
<head>
</head>
<script src="scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<body>
<h1>address</h1>
<hr/>
<label>please select state</label>
<select id="slctstate"></select>
<br />
<br />
<label>please select city</label>
<select id="slctcity"></select>
</body>
</head>
```

it is script.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.getJSON("get_stat.php", success = function(data){
    var options = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < data.lenght; i++)
        {
        options += "<option value='" + data[i].toLowerCase() + "'>" + data[i] +      "</option>";
        }
        $("#sltstate").append(options);
});
$("#slctstate").change(function(){
    $.getJSON("get_city.php?state=" +$(this).value(), success = function(data){
    var options = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < data.lenght; i++)
        {
        options += "<option value='" + data[i].toLowerCase() + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>";
        }
        $("#slctcity").append(options);
    });
});
```

});

it is get_state.php

```
<?php 
require "Connections/dbopen.php";

$query = "SELECT state_name FROM states";
$data = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$states = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
{
array_push($states, $row["state_name"]);    
}
echo json_encode($states);

require "Connections/dbclose.php";
```

?>

and hers is get_city.php

```
<?php 
require "Connections/dbopen.php";
if(isset($_GET["$state"]));
{
$state = $_GET["state"];
$query = "SELECT city_name FROM city
INNER JOIN states ON
city.state_id=states.state_id
WHERE state_name LIKE '{$state}'"; 

$data = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$city = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
{
array_push($city, $row["city_name"]);   
}
echo json_encode($city);
require "Connections/dbclose.php";
}
```

?>

but at the final step i did not get any value in my drop down can any one please help me thanks

Comment: in `script.js`, `length` is misspelled in `for(var i = 0; i < data.lenght; i++)` (both times used)

Comment: also, `id="slctstate"` != `#sltstate`

Comment: also `$.getJSON("get_stat.php",` != `get_state.php`

Comment: change `success = function(data){` to `function(data){` in `script.js`, and `if(isset($_GET["$state"]))` to `if(isset($_GET["state"]))` in `get_city.php`,

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make the following changes:

- change lenght to length
- change success = function(data) to function(data)
- change isset($_GET["$state"]) to isset($_GET["state"])
- refer to http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php for fetching data in an easier way(optional if the first 3 changes dont work)

Comment: thanks for your reply i try all of this but still not working